# convert single string object to array (or regular object)

Tags: javascript, json, string, object

i have a POST request body being sent as

```json
{'{"thingy":"stuff","otherThing":"moreStuff","notAnActualKey":':{'"random"':''}}
```

(the above is not the actual data but the parenthesis, commas, brackets, quotation marks etc. are EXACTLY the same as the way my data is being returned)

the data is coming from SalesForce Apex, and i cannot change the way it is sent out

i have a program written in TypeScript to use the data.

i need to turn the data into an array.

when i run `typeof()` on it it returns `object` but when i use `keys()` or `values()` on it, i get an error

```
TypeError: requestBody.keys is not a function
```

or

```
TypeError: requestBody.values is not a function
```

i assumed it was still JSON, but when i use `JSON.parse(requestBody)` on it i get an error

```
Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
```

which means it's already an object

i don't understand what it is. how can i get the data from it turned into an array?

Comment: That SalesForce whatever output stinks on broken data. Anyways. `{'` is invalid JSON. Read more: https://www.json.org/json-en.html You either made a huge mistake in interpreting, simplifying for us that string(?) or something is really wrong.

Comment: So there is a JSON object with a key that is a string that contains more JSON data?  `'{"thingy":"stuff","otherThing":"moreStuff","notAnActualKey":'` is a key in the object?  Single quotes aren't allowed in JSON so that will break regardless.

Comment: Have you tried [`Object.keys(requestBody)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`Object.values(requestBody)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)?

Comment: The `keys` and `values` are the static methods defined on the `Object`, e.g.: `Object.keys({'{"thingy":"stuff","otherThing":"moreStuff","notAnActualKey":':{'"random"':''}})`

Comment: What do you get with Object.prototype.toString.call(requestBody);

Comment: Do you really get something that ends like that: `"notAnActualKey":'`, i.e. an encoded property without value after the colon?

Comment: @yoni The object which you posted is looks like a broken one. It should be something like this `'{"thingy": "stuff", "otherThing": "moreStuff", "notAnActualKey": {"random": ""}}'`  Now, when you said `I need to turn the data into an array` - what does it mean ? What would be the structure of that array ?

Answer (score 0):

*you can try sometihng like this way :*

```js
let str = `{'{"thingy":"stuff","otherThing":"moreStuff","notAnActualKey":':{'"random"':''}}`;

let jsObjRealstr = str.replaceAll(`''`,`""`)
                      .replaceAll(`'`,``)
                      .replaceAll(`::`,`:`)
                      .replace(`{{`,`{`);
                      
console.log( JSON.parse(jsObjRealstr ) );
```